# C Memory leak issue

Tags: c, memory-leaks

Program is leaking memory and not able to fix it... This Program is reading data from text files and after reading data, it perform certain operation on data during this it leaks memory. Device has very limited memory & flash drive due to this I cannot run memory leaks checking tools. 
Please advise to fix the memory leak issue
Please find code snippet below

```
int LanguageRequiredData(void)
{

   char *data=NULL;
   int retValue = 0 ;

   retValue = GetString_English(&data);
   if(retValue>0 && strlen(data)>0)
   {
      // Do Some Operation
   }

   if (data!=NULL)
  {
      Mem_free(data);
      data = NULL;
  }
}


int GetString_English(char **data)
{

    int retValue = 0 ;

    retValue = File_LoadContent(LANGSENGFILE,&(*data));

    return retValue;
}


int File_LoadContent (char *file, char **content) 
{

   long size = File_Size(file); 
   char buf[256]={};

   memset(buf,0x00,sizeof(buf));
   if (*content)
  {
    Mem_free(*content);
  }
  *content = (char*) Mem_alloc((size+1) * sizeof(char));

  TFILE * fd; fd=File_Open(file,"r"); if (fd==NULL) return 0;
  while (File_Gets(buf,sizeof(buf),fd)!=NULL)
  {
    strcat(*content,buf);
    memset(buf,0x00,sizeof(buf));
  }
  File_Close(fd); return 1;
}


void * Mem_alloc(size_t size)
{
   int    i;
   void * ptr = NULL;

   for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
   {
      ptr = malloc(size);

      if (ptr)
      {
         break;
      }
   }

  if (ptr)
  {
      memset(ptr, 0, size);
   }

  return ptr;
}

void Mem_free(void * ptr)
{    
   if (ptr != NULL)
  { 
     free(ptr);
  }

  ptr = NULL;    
}
```

Comment: and what did you try till time?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: You mind creating a [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Unrelated, but your `Mem_free` function is not necessary. You can just call `free` because it's OK to call `free` on a NULL pointer.

Comment: And what's this `for` loop in your `Mem_alloc` function? That's really fishy.

Comment: this code is leaking memory or not ? how can we confirm this

Comment: @JosephCenk in your question you pretend that your program is leaking memory and now you ask __how__ you can confirm that the program is leaking memory or not. So what is your question in first place?

Comment: @MichaelWalz for loop will break if it allocates memory... I am sure it is leaking memory after this code execution it corrupts memory.

Comment: Are you sure of your `File_size` function, from `strcat` man page :  If  dest  is  not   large  enough, program behavior is unpredictable

Comment: @Ôrel File size is simple function

    long File_Size (char *file) {
        TFILE *fd; long size=0; fd=File_Open(file,"r"); if (fd==NULL) return 0;
        fseek(fd, 0L, SEEK_END); size = File_Tell(fd); File_Close(fd); return size;
      }

Comment: @JosephCenk I don't see anything obviously wrong in the code you posted. The problem may be elsewhere.

Comment: As said in the deleted answer, avoid casting the result of malloc and posting pseudo-code.

Comment: By the way, your `Mem_alloc()` function, which initialises an area to zero, can be done using the standard library function `calloc()`.

Comment: `char buf[256]={}; memset(buf,0x00,sizeof(buf));` can be replace with `char buf[256]={0};`

Comment: My advice is to avoid malloc. If you have enough RAM to malloc buffers for the largest file read, then you can do a static allocation big enough to accommodate that largest file. Then you don't need to use malloc at all. Problem solved.

Comment: @barny I just have 64MB RAM available... if I load all data into stack then it will crash... so dynamic memory allocation is best option available..

Comment: I said a STATIC allocation, declared outside a function, so not on a stack. Personally I'd jump through hoops to avoid using malloc, it's a recipe for this sort of question.

Answer (score 0):

This part seems suspect:

```
  while (File_Gets(buf,sizeof(buf),fd)!=NULL)
  {
    strcat(*content,buf);
    memset(buf,0x00,sizeof(buf));
  }
```

Specifically the `strcat()`.  Is `File_Gets()` null-terminating what it writes to `buf[]`?  If not then the `strcat()` may be reading/copying beyond the bounds of `buf[]`, since it requires null-termination to know when to stop.

EDIT: I should point out that this is one of the reasons to recommend `strncat()` over `strcat()`.  Using the "n" variants of the string functions (i.e. `strncat()`, `strncpy()`, `strncmp()`) helps prevent buffer overruns and is generally a good practice.